# Me sale este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"','"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\eva\php\insertar.php on line 20

Tags: php

y la linea 20 es esta :

```
$sql="insert into empleado (rut, nombre, edad, estado_civil, genero, locomocion) 
            values (".$rut.",'".$nombre."','".$edad."','".$estado_civil"','".$genero."','".$locomocion."')";
```

Answer (score 2):

No estás concatenando correctamente en **".$estado_civil"',** te falta un punto: **".$estado_civil."',**

Cuando delimitas una cadena con comillas dobles no es necesario concatenar, PHP interpretará las variables, quedando más legible y evitando errores como el que tienes ahora:

```
$sql="insert into empleado (rut, nombre, edad, estado_civil, genero, locomocion) 
    values ($rut,'$nombre','$edad','$estado_civil','$genero','$locomocion')";
```

Adicionalmente: Usa un editor con coloreado de sintaxis, generalmente te marcarán estos errores.

Comment: muchas gracias!